# deleted object would be re-saved by cascade issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I know that there are few similar questions on **stackoverflow** but unfortunately it didn't help me so I'm creating my own.
In my project i have two entities `Shop` and `TypeShop` with EAGER initialization. `TypeShop` may have a few shops.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_types")
public class TypeShop {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="typeShop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Shop> shops;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shops")
public class Shop {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_type_id")
    private TypeShop typeShop;
    ...
}
```

Here is code of controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteShop(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    try {
        shopDAO.delete(id);
    } catch (Exception e ) {          
        return "404";
    }
    return "redirect:/admin";
}
```

Trying to delete `shop` object i get `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)`

So after that i modified my code and before deleting `shop` I remove it from parent `Set collection`. 
And now it looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteShop(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    try {
        Shop shop = shopDAO.findById(id);
        TypeShop type = shop.getTypeShop();
        type.getShops().remove(shop);
        typeShopDAO.update(type);
        shopDAO.delete(id);
    } catch (Exception e ) { 
        return "404";
    }
    return "redirect:/admin";
}
```

But unfortunately i get the same exception again. Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to remove the other side of the association? (Setting `typeShop` in `shop` to null).

Comment: shopService.delete(id) wont work, you have to pass shop object. try this.

Comment: thanks, but actually in my real project I'm using DAO layer and Service layer, and I call method delete from DAO class, DAO class receives Integer but inside method I find my object by this id and delete it through session.delete(object), so it is not a problem

Comment: that obviously will be in another transaction so hibernate doesn't know whether the typeshop object is updated or not

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the shop object instead of shop id and move the code to ShopService class,  And it should be inside a transaction.

```
@Transactional    
public void deleteShop(Integer id){
            Shop shop = shopDAO.findById(id);
            TypeShop type = shop.getTypeShop();
            type.getShops().remove(shop);
            typeShopDAO.update(type);
            shopDAO.delete(shop);
    }
```

Comment: see my comment above, i simplified my code in this question

Comment: create another method which takes shop object or move this entire code to shop dao.